# Changing line color in console output - IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I have red lines in my console output like this: 
[image]

How can I change color for this lines? I was looking in settings for this option but I couldnt find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the console colors here:

[image: colors]